# Refresh the react component every 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in the page in which I want to fetch the latest state of the page by refreshing the component every 30 seconds,

for example in this data is coming from the server and the id and names are constantly added and removed. Instead of refreshing the page manually everytime can we do the refresh of the component Datatable every 30 sec so as to ensure we have the latest data.

How can I do this.
Is setInterval the right way or ShouldComponentUpdate will do the trick ?

Edit : Need to just edit the table instead of the whole component

```
export class DataTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.context.store.dispatch(getData());
    }

    componentDidMount(){
           this.updateTimer = setInterval(() => this.context.store.dispatch(getData()), 30000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.updateTimer);
}
    
    _getDtableProps() {
        const arr = this.props.getData.data;
        const data = arr.map((d, i) => {
            return {    
                'id': this.formatPathId(d['id']),
                'name': this.formatTime(d['name'])
            }
        })
        return {
            data,
            dtOptions: {
                order: [2, "desc"]
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    title: 'Id',
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'name',
                    title: 'Name',
                    searchable: true
                }
            ]

        }
    }


    render() {
           let tableProps = this._getDtableProps();
            return (       
                <div className={style.container}>
                    <Table {...tableProps}/>
                </div>
                
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a good example of this scenario given in the [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) documentation. The example implements a clock that updates every second. It uses `setInterval` in `componentDidMount` to update the time. The interval is removed with `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, `setInterval` is the way to go. `shouldComponentUpdate` wouldn't get called at a schedule.

In a classic class-based component, you'll want to set up a timer in `componentDidMount`, e.g.

```
this.updateTimer = setInterval(() => this.loadNewData(), 30000);
```

and remove it at `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
clearInterval(this.updateTimer);
```

Comment: I have edited the code ,its still not working - can you please advice.

Comment: interval for refreshing keeps on increasing. for first it refreshes once then the component refreshes twice and so on

Comment: I said `componentDidMount`, not `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Is there any chance I can update the table contents instead of refreshing the whole componeent ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is setInterval in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
   // any your code ....
   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
     // code to refresh your component.
   },30000)
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code ,its still not working - can you please advice.

Comment: interval for refreshing keeps on increasing. for first it refreshes once then the component refreshes twice and so on

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, in this case I use this pattern:

```
  state = {
     ...
     delay: 30000,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, this.state.delay);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.delay !== this.state.delay) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, this.state.delay);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  tick = () => {
    // load new data here
  }
```

I put `delay` on state to modify `setInterval` delay in case I want increase/reduce interval time.